# How to get a list of all internet explorers open for all users on a machine?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, console-application

The following code lists all urls from the address bars of all open Internet Explorers. But it's only for the currently logged in user. I would like to get all open Internet Explorer urls for ALL users logged in on the machine. Is that possible?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
        {
            string url = ieInst.LocationURL;

            if (url.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get this code to work, I reference c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll

Comment: Why?   You'll need admin privs and inject DLLs into various remote processes...   Very difficult to get right, and terribly likely to go wrong, resulting in information leakage (in the best case) or random AVs (in the worst case).

Comment: @EricBrown I can easily list all running processes for all users on a machine. I don't get why listing all open Windows for all users is such a pain?

Comment: The kernel knows about processes.   It doesn't know about `SHDocVw`; that's a user-mode entity.   Since it's a user-mode entity, you have to enumerate the windows *in each user session*.  Clearer now?

Comment: @EricBrown Yes. Crystal. Do you have a simple code example that does that?

Comment: No. It's a BAD IDEA.

Comment: @EricBrown Why would it be a bad idea? Do you have code that does what you say or not?

Comment: Because *you're not the kernel*.  No, I'm not going to write a kernel driver for you.